# Regular expression not to allow the string to have any special characters except+ plus and alphabets 

Tags: regex

I have to validate a simple text which is depicting a phone number. It should allow only numbers and a Plus sign if the user enters. Alphabets, other special characters and spaces should not be allowed. I need a java script with the Regular expression to match only + and numbers. Please help

Comment: Your title is very confusing and doesn't seem to say the same thing as your question. Can you please reword it?

Answer (score 2):

Here a basic one it will accept an optional + and one or more numbers after it
\+?[0-9]+

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var myRegex = /^[0-9+]+$/;
```

If you only want to allow the `+` at the start then try this:

```
var myRegex = /^\+?\d+$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Phone number varies from countries to countries.. so you need to be very specific about the country and phone number pattern.. e.g like length, area code, phone number, etc. After that regular expression can be designed.

Comment: I just want to check numbers.. it should not contain alphabets or special chars or any spaces.. Just allow + sign and only numbers